# Stokes’ Theorem - On Conservative Vector Fields and Whether Parametrization is Always Necessary/Helpful?

Tags: integration, vector-fields, stokes-theorem, bounds-of-integration

In my physics class, we are working on problems using Stokes’ Theorem - but unfortunately we didn’t go over a single example Problem and it’s missing from our textbook! Now, when searching the Internet, it seems that you usually solve for the surface integral using parametrization - but is this strictly necessary? Can you use Stokes’ theorem while remaining in Cartesian coordinates?

Specifically, we are looking to apply Stokes’ theorem to a conservative vector field bounded by the shape with vertices at (1,0,0), (0,1,0) and (0,0,2).

Also, is it valid to set up a triple integral of this problem, integrating the function zero? The problem is that when I try to solve it this way, I get that the answer is just zero, which is not the same answer as I got for the path integral. Could someone maybe provide a hint?

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Stokes Theorem (loosely) says $\int_{\partial S}F\cdot d\vec{r}=\int\int_S\big(\text{curl}(F)\cdot\vec{n}\big)dS$ where $S$ is a surface and $\partial{S}$ is its boundary which, in your case, is a closed triangle with vertices $(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,2)$. The normal $\vec{n}$ of $S$ is pointing in a direction that *induces the orientation assigned to* $\partial S$. A natural surface whose boundary is the triangle you're referring to is the plane $z=-2x-2y+2$ defined on the domain $0\leq y \leq 1-x,0\leq x \leq 1$ which you should note is a function of the Cartesian variables $x$ and $y$.

Comment: This cartesian representation of $S$ will allow you to express the surface integral $\int\int_S\big(\text{curl}(F)\cdot\vec{n}\big)dS$ with the cartesian variables you know and love. Also, since the vector field is conservative, we would necessarily have $\text{curl}(F)=\vec{0}$ so you should get a vanishing path integral. Also note that Stokes Theorem doesn't involve triple integrals. That's Gauss' divergence theorem.

Comment: You didn't say whether you were in fact finding the flux of the curl. But if you have a conservative force, its curl is $0$, and the line integral of a conservative force around a closed curve is always $0$. So ... $0=0$.

Comment: Thank you! Actually, we weren’t given that the vector field was conservative; I took the curl and found that the curl was zero and since it is around a closed shape —> conservative. However, I am confused, because I thought you could only apply Stokes’ theorem to conservative vector fields. Then, if the curl for any vector field is zero overall, that would mean that all conservative vector fields have both surface integral and path integral equal to zero...and surely that can’t be right! @TedShifrin

Comment: I highly recommend you visit this site to get some practice problems with Stokes' Theorem: https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/StokesTheorem.aspx

Comment: Also, thank you@MatthewPilling ! However, the formulas we were given is that the surface integral (double integral) is the Curl or the Vector field dotted with dA. Where did you get this other vector n? Also, using that line z=-2x-2y+2, that’s very cool and interesting, but wouldn’t you also need z=2x+2y+2 and then with your other bounds for x and y respectively, how is that not a triple integral? Sorry if these are really stupid questions, but you have to start somewhere!

Comment: Thank you - I’m looking at that resource now. I guess I am wondering, can we even apply Stoke’s theorem to a non conservative field? An example on that website is similar but the curl is (2z-1)j and that is not zero...I thought Stoke’s theorem was only valid for a conservative vector field?

Comment: Stokes' Theorem applies to any vector field $F$ with continuous first partial derivatives. The vector field doesn't have to be conservative. Also, you want to think of $d\vec{A}$ as an "oriented" surface area component, so that $d\vec{A}=\vec{n}dA$ where $\vec{n}$ is normal to the surface $S$. That's why in the notes I sent you they write $d\vec{S}=\vec{n}dS$. Also, the domain of integral for a triple integral is a three dimensional solid, not a two dimension region. Lastly, if you include the surface $z=2x+2y+2$ you're looking at an entirely different triangular$-$shaped surface.

Comment: In the previous remarks, you want to think of $dA$ (which is $dS$ in the notes I sent you) as the surface area of a teeny$-$tiny patch of the surface $S$ in your double integral. (Please note I wrote $dA$, not $d\vec{A}$)

Comment: Thanks so much, @MatthewPilling, I referenced the notes, but ended up with I believe the wrong answer, based on checking homework with classmates. Maybe the problem is that I did the last face in the xy plane, after substituting for z in terms of x and y - while this triangle is in terms of x,y, and z (all three variables) - but without reducing it to 2 variables I’m not sure I understand how it would not be taking a triple integral? And also, is there any example of someone taking the path integral in 3D without using the parametrization, or should I just look up how to do the paramtrizarion?